# Call to web services not working in Passkit (webServiceURL)

Tags: ios, json, passbook, passkit

I have an application that generates passes for the Apple Wallet. The application is made in Ruby on Rails with the gem *dubai*.
I can create a coupon and it works in the iPhone Simulator.
The problem is that if I put the *webServiceURL* property with the Web Services address on the coupon, the Simulator cannot read the coupon and also does not show an error on the screen or in the log (Console).
The Simulator has *"Allow http services"* enabled and is on the same network. The RoR application has the Services implemented and has the correct Certificates, *passTypeIdentifier* and *teamIdentifier* correct.

There is no error in the application logs or in the Simulator logs. Only the pass does not work when I set the *webServiceURL* option.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ok,

I tried to read the pass from a Macbook and I could read the log.
"authenticationToken" is too short.
A silly bug but it doesn't appear in the Simulator logs.

Comment: Thanks @hazardco! I must've missed that key in the documentation and for that reason whenever I generated a pass WITH webServiceURL, it wouldn't let me add it, but WITHOUT it everything worked - I spent nearly 2 hours on that and I would've spent more if I didn't find this...